# Pass database parameter into peewee Meta class

Tags: python, peewee, scoping

I am using [peewee](https://github.com/coleifer/peewee) to manage CRUD operations on a Postgres database.

In [the project documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html#quickstart), connection to the database and creation of the ORM should be setup through a `Meta` class which other ORM types should inherit.

```
from peewee import *
db = PostgresqlDatabase('table', **{})

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
class Product(BaseModel):
    name = CharField(unique=True)
```

I'd like to be able to encapsulate this setup in a `Persistence` class, like as follows (so as not to create any global variables):

```
class Persistence():
    db = None

    class BaseModel(Model):
        class Meta:
            database = Persistence.db
    class Product(BaseModel):
        name = CharField(unique=True)

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = PostgresqlDatabase('table', **{})
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work with:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Persistence' has no attribute 'db'
```

I don't think this would work as expected (disregarding the `AttributeError`), because even if the variable was in scope at the time of the creation of `BaseModel`, it would be `None` and not change when the `Persistence` class is instantiated.

1. Is there a way to scope the `db` variable correctly so that it uses a class attribute on `Persistence`?
2. Can I pass in this `db` connection to `peewee` through another mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue confuses two separate issues. Python scoping and Peewee database initialization. It'd be helpful if you were clear on where exactly the issue lies.

For the peewee part of your question, you probably want to defer initialization of the database. To do this, you create a database object placeholder -- or use a `Proxy` depending on how late you want to defer things.

Example of deferred initialization:

```
db = SqliteDatabase(None)

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

# Declare other models as subclasses of BaseModel, e.g.
class Foo(BaseModel):
    data = TextField()

class Persistence(object):
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        db.init(db_file)
```

Alternatively you can use a proxy, which is documented here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of 'Using' execution contexts to have dynamic db connections. For example I have something like this:

```
from peewee import *
from playhouse.shortcuts import RetryOperationalError

from config import settings

class RetryMySQLDatabase(RetryOperationalError, MySQLDatabase):
    pass

db_connection = {}
for conn in settings.DB:
    dbs = settings.DB[conn]
    db_connection[conn] = RetryMySQLDatabase(
                                dbs["DB_NAME"], 
                                host=dbs["DB_HOST"], 
                                user=dbs["DB_USER"], 
                                password=dbs["DB_PASS"]
                            )

db = db_connection["default"] #if you don't want to have default connection, you can make use of Proxy() here

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Booking(BaseModel):
    id = BigIntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    name = CharField(db_column='NAME', null=True)
```

And, while using the model class you can specify which db connection to use:

```
with Using(db_connection["read_only"], [Booking]):
    booking_data = Booking.get(Booking.id == 123)
```

Ref:

'**Using**' execution context: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/2.10.2/peewee/database.html?highlight=re#using-multiple-databases

**Proxy** class: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database

Comment: References outdated apis.